# Using for loop to save multiple files

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to mirror multiple images and save them to my folder.
Though I mirrored all my images, I have no idea how to save them into separate files by using loop. I need to save each files and want to name them as their original files.

```
import os
import glob
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps

path_to_jpeg = 'C:\\Users\\Ky\\Desktop\\imageFlipTest'
jpeg_files = os.listdir(path_to_jpeg)

mirrored_image = []
for jpeg_file in jpeg_files:
    if jpeg_file.endswith('left.jpeg'):
        mi_jpeg = Image.open(jpeg_file)
        mi_jpeg = ImageOps.mirror(mi_jpeg)
        mi_jpeg.show()
        mi_jpeg.save("")
```

Answer (score 0):

`save()` with the iteration variable:

```
import os
import glob
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps

path_to_jpeg = 'C:\\Users\\Ky\\Desktop\\imageFlipTest'
jpeg_files = os.listdir(path_to_jpeg)

mirrored_image = []
for jpeg_file in jpeg_files:
    if jpeg_file.endswith('left.jpeg'):
        mi_jpeg = Image.open(jpeg_file)
        mi_jpeg = ImageOps.mirror(mi_jpeg)
        mi_jpeg.show()
        mi_jpeg.save(path_to_jpeg+'\\'+jpeg_file.replace('left','right'))
```

Comment: I also would like to rename each file. If file contains 'left', I want to change it to 'right'.

Comment: check edit please, you can perform `replace` and other methods/operations on `jpeg_file`